# Athletes who have won medals in multiple disciplines in the same Olympics games

Tags: trivia, olympics

Has there been any male or female athlete who won medals in multiple disciplines during the same Olympics game? If so, list the athlete's name, as well as the year, and the disciplines of medal winning. As bonus, also list any other discipline if the athlete also participated in that year, but didn't win a medal for.

To clarify, I consider sport programs to be of different discipline if 
listed so here for each of [summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_sports#Current_and_discontinued_summer_program) and [winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_sports#Current_winter_program) games.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_athletes_with_Olympic_medals_in_different_disciplines check this list

Comment: That only partially answers my question. If an athlete has done this in multiple Olympics games, it wouldn't be easy to tell from that list. Also the winter and summer Olympics used to get hosted on the same year until 1992 which makes it tough to tell if an anyone in that list with only one year entry qualifies for this answer in a quick look.

Comment: i think you have been pointed to a source where you can find info -- if you make an effort.

Comment: Stack Exchange has a strict policy against LMGTFY and *your answer is in another castle* as answers. Attempting to answer in comments is a further problem.

Answer (score 1):

As of yesterday 20-Feb-2018:
Jorien ter Mors (NED) won gold at 1000m speed skating (14-Feb-2018) and bronze at team relay short track skating (20-Feb-2018) at the 2018 Winter Olympics in Korea.
Fun fact: NED was in the B-final and managed a new world and olympic record. After two penalties in the A-final they were bumped up to third place.

And I found a link to [Frank Kugler](http://www.topendsports.com/events/summer/athletes/kugler-frank.htm) winning a medal in 3 different sports in the 1904 Olympics.

Of course there's als Carl Lewis 100m sprint and long jump (I remember him, must be others as well) but according to the table in the opening question all Athletics is considered one sport.

Edit 2018-02-26: And I was trying to remember Esther Ledecka... who won gold in both alpine skiing and snowboard in the 2018 Winter Olympics.